# Generating gamma random field with given covariance matrix

Tags: random-generation, gamma-distribution

I have to generate multivariate gamma distributions with given positive-definite covariance matrix. Anyone can suggest me a method?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(clusterGeneration)
genPositiveDefMat(dim,...) #Where  dim is the dimension of the matrix, explore the   #function
```

You can now use any package that will generate a multivariate gamma in R using the positive definite matrix above.

Answer (score 0):

This article, "Gamma random field simulation by a covariance matrix transformation method
" (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%252Fs00477-010-0434-8), should help you.

Comment: Please add the reference of the paper in case the link dies in the future. Thanks!

Comment: And if possible, provide a brief summary of how the paper is helpful here